# Adding an event listener to a submit button to run a function

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

Hey guys I'm writing an app with javascript and I'm trying to add an event listener to the submit button which is the "Send Email" button that someone clicks to send an email.

I know the code works for adding the email since when i run it outside of an event listener, it sends the email.  So there's an issue with my event listener for some reason.

Currently - nothing happens when I click the send mail button. I get no error it just returns me to the inbox.

I'm sure the event listener isn't working for some reason.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

html:

```
<div id="compose-view">
        <h3>New Email</h3>
        <form id="compose-form"
        method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                From: <input disabled class="form-control" value="{{ request.user.email }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                To: <input id="compose-recipients" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" id="sendEmail" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

js:

```
 const element = document.getElementById('sendEmail');
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    fetch('/emails', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      recipients: 'card51short@gmail.com',
      subject: "buglets",
      body: 'Hes a fat one'
    })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
      // Print result
      console.log(result);
  });
  });
}
```

Comment: attach breakpoints inside that listener and check what happens. Also keep an eye on the browser console

Comment: submit buttons submit forms

Comment: it is a form, right?

Answer (score 0):

Its because your form method is post which is going to make a post request when you click the button and the javascript isn't going to run because it is attempting to make a post request to an endpoint that doesn't exist. So you need to remove the html attribute `method` from the form.

Comment: hey thanks so much for the help. I removed the method attribute and I'm still getting the same results! my form tag is just this now: <form id="compose-form">.  Any other issues you see?